# RowCount() = 0 error php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rowcount

```
echo "<h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>";

            if ($sth7->rowCount()) {
                while($row7 = $sth7->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<div class='comment'>{$row7['usr']} said";
                }
            }
            else($sth7->rowCount() = 0)                                                          
            echo "User";

Can't use method return value in write context
```

Why doesnt that rowcount() = 0 logic work?

Answer (score 3):

= is the assignment operator in PHP.

You're basically trying to assign 0 to $sth7->rowCount().

Perhaps you mean $sth7->rowCount() == 0?

Also, you really don't need the if else if.  It could be just an if else:

```
if($sth7->rowCount()) {

} else {

}
```

rowCount() returns an integer, and any integer except for 0 will cast to true.

Answer (score 2):

Try `rowcount() == 0` to compare with 0, your code (`rowcount() = 0`) tries to assign 0. Also, it's may be useful to put constant on the left side while comparing : (`0 == rowcount()`) to make such errors easier to detect.

Comment: This does not work: `else($sth7->rowcount() == 0){               
       echo "User";
      }`

Comment: it should be `else if ($sth7->rowcount() == 0)` (or just `else`)

Answer (score 0):

`else` doesn't take any logic, it just runs if it's assosciated if (and any elseifs) didn't evaluate true.

Also, `=` is an assignment operator - read it as "becomes equal to"

```
$var = 1; // Var becomes equal to 1
```

`==` is an equality operator, it tests if two expressions are equal

```
$var == 1 // Var is equal to 1
```

---

You probably want

```
else if ($sth7->rowCount() == 0)                                                          
     echo "User";
```